# Previous/Next Post - Cannot Display Featured Image

Tags: post-thumbnails

I need help with displaying the featured image of the previous/next post.

I'm not a coder and have been trying to search for solutions in this forum & online.

Here are my codes (single.php):

```
<?php $prevPost = get_adjacent_post( false, '', true );
    if($prevPost):
?>

<a class="previous" href="<?= get_permalink($prevPost->ID); ?>">
    <p><?= $prevPost->post_title; ?></p>
</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```

How do I output the featured image of the Previous Post?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Alvin

Answer (score 0):

featured image url function passed post id and image size

```
<?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($prevPost->ID,'full'); ?>

<img src="<?php echo $featured_img_url; ?>" />
```